# How to automate Jenkins work scenarios using UFT?

Tags: jenkins, hp-uft

I'm setting up a UFT Testcase, where I need to login to Jenkins and perform few operations like creating new jobs. Though I'm able to identify objects using object spy, I'm not able to identify while running the scripts. I'm using descriptive programming. If there are any related material or solution for this, it would be helpful. Also, please let me know if there are any limitations in automating Jenkins. Thanks in advance!

Associated Add-ins: ActiveX,Web,Java
Jenkins version: 2.150.2
UFT version: 14.03
I'm able to automate login if I'm declaring each field as an object. But If I hard code it, then the script is not identifying the objects. I tried inputting all the parameters for each field, even then it's not working.
Please find the code below, where I just highlight and set username field to XXXX

**Code**

```
wait(2)    
If Browser("title:=Sign in [Jenkins]").Page("title:=Sign in [Jenkins]").WebEdit("name:=j_username","html tag:=INPUT","html id:=j_username").Exist(10) Then    
    Browser("title:=Sign in [Jenkins]").Page("title:=Sign in [Jenkins]").WebEdit("name:=j_username","html tag:=INPUT","html id:=j_username").highlight    
    Browser("title:=Sign in [Jenkins]").Page("title:=Sign in [Jenkins]").WebEdit("name:=j_username","html tag:=INPUT","type:=text").Set "XXXX"    
else    
    print("Object was not recognized")    
End IF
```

Comment: Thats not possible using UFT. Jenkins is a build automation tool. You can right some groovy script to init Jenkins and create jobs but not thorough vbscript and UFT, even if you are using selenium , that wont be possible

Comment: @mbn217 Why wouldn't it be possible?  It's essentially just automating a web site like any other.  OP will need to provide more information regarding your code/selected addons and examples of your descriptive programming if you want anyone to be able to help you.  Currently there isn't enough information.

Comment: What specific problems are you facing?

Comment: I **think** that the values used in descriptive programming are considered by default to be regular expressions and the `[]` chars may be throwing off your expectations.  Try adding a backslash \ character before each of the square brackets and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave! That solved the problem.